# Mockito Mock a static void method with Mockito.mockStatic()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using Spring Boot and in one of my unit test, I need to mock the `Files.delete(somePath)` function. Which is a static void method.

I know that with Mockito it is possible to mock void method:

```
doNothing().when(MyClass.class).myVoidMethod()
```

And since July 10th 2020, it is possible to mock static method:

```
try (MockedStatic<MyStaticClass> mockedStaticClass = Mockito.mockStatic(MyStaticClass.class)) {
    mockedStaticClass.when(MyStaticClass::giveMeANumber).thenReturn(1L);
    assertThat(MyStaticClass.giveMeANumber()).isEqualTo(1L);
  }
```

But I can't manage to mock a static void mehtod such as `Files.delete(somePath)`.

This is my pom.xml file (only test related dependencies):

```yaml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.15</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.15</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.15</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to mock static void methods without using PowerMockito ?
If it is possible, what is the correct syntax to do so ?

Comment: did you add mockito-inline as dependencies ?

Comment: Yes I did, I will edit my question to add my POM.xml file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general mocking static calls is the last resort, that is not supposed to be used as default approach.

For example, for testing the code, that works with file system, there are better means. E.g. depending on the `junit` version either use [`TemporaryFolder` rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) or [`@TempDir` annotation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html).

Also, please note, that `Mockito.mockStatic` might significantly slow down your tests (e.g. look at the notes below).

Having said the caution above, find the snippet below, that shows how to test, that file got removed.

```
class FileRemover {
    public static void deleteFile(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        Files.delete(filePath);
    }
}

class FileRemoverTest {

    @TempDir
    Path directory;

    @Test
    void fileIsRemovedWithTemporaryDirectory() throws IOException {
        Path fileToDelete = directory.resolve("fileToDelete");
        Files.createFile(fileToDelete);

        FileRemover.deleteFile(fileToDelete);

        assertFalse(Files.exists(fileToDelete));
    }

    @Test
    void fileIsRemovedWithMockStatic() throws IOException {
        Path fileToDelete = Paths.get("fileToDelete");
        try (MockedStatic<Files> removerMock = Mockito.mockStatic(Files.class)) {
            removerMock.when(() -> Files.delete(fileToDelete)).thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
            // alternatively
            // removerMock.when(() -> Files.delete(fileToDelete)).thenAnswer(Answers.RETURNS_DEFAULTS);

            FileRemover.deleteFile(fileToDelete);

            removerMock.verify(() -> Files.delete(fileToDelete));
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `Mockito.mockStatic` is available in Mockito 3.4 and above, so check you're using correct version.
2. The snippet deliberatly shows two approaches: `@TempDir` and `Mockito.mockStatic`. When run both tests you'll notice that `Mockito.mockStatic` is much slower. E.g. on my system test with `Mockito.mockStatic` runs around 900 msec vs 10 msec for `@TempDir`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I knew that mocking static method was not a good practice but I didn't know it was that slow. Thanks for explaining the proper way to do it, I will implement it.

Answer (score 5):

Use mockStatic and then specify the mock in the returned instance.

```
try (MockedStatic<Files> mockFiles = Mockito.mockStatic(Files.class)) {
    mockFiles.when(() -> Files.delete(anyString()))
                     .then(invocationOnMock -> null);
}
```