# How to skip static validation in JUnit test with Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a function I need to test:

```
    @Override
public ResponseEntity<BasicResponse> myFunction(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Dto dto,  BindingResult result) {
    
    try {
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, dto, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // do things            
        } else {
            //do things
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catch
    }

    //return things;
}
```

But when I test the function it always go to the catch because of the validator, it says:
"Validator does not support Dto".

I don't care about the validation, I need to test what's inside the try, so I try to use doNothing to skip the validation but I get an error because it's void:

```
    @Test
void TestMyFunction() {
    doNothing().when(ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, dto, result));
    ResponseEntity<BasicResponse> response = controller.myFunction(request, dto, result);
    // assert something
}
```

Any idea on how to proceed? I can't change the function, I can only write the test and I'm new at this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `ValidationUtils` was an object instance that is a Mockito [spy or mock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing), you would be able to mock it [like so](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

```java
doNothing()
    .when(validationUtils)
    .invokeValidator(validator, dto, result);
```

This, unfortunately, does not seem to be the case in your test - `ValidationUtils` seems to be a class on which a static method is called, which Mockito [can handle since version 3.4.0](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48) (before that it was usually handled by [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)). `thenAnswer` should be used with the `mockedStatic` object instance, similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464855/3305737), since the method's return type is void.

An important additional (but mandatory) note: mocking static methods is discouraged and should be avoided whenever possible. It slows down the tests and is a sign of bad design of the classes. The validator should be injected into the class or created using a factory, thanks to that a mocked object instance could be easily used.

---

I've checked that and in fact the `thenAnswer` part is not required to do nothing after using `mockStatic` on a class.

```java
try (var mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ValidationUtils.class)) {
    // test code
}
```

The code above makes `ValidationUtils` do nothing and return default values (`0`, `false`, `null`).

See [this example](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/mockito/mock-static/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/MockitoStaticVoidTest.java#L115) (all tests pass).