# How to write Mockito.when() for Json.mapper().constructType(type)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Can anyone tell me how to mock and write Mockito.when() method for

```
@Override
public Property resolveProperty(Type type, ModelConverterContext context, Annotation[] annotations, Iterator<ModelConverter> chain) {
   JavaType jType = Json.mapper().constructType(type);
   ...
}
```

I wrote

```
when(Json.mapper()).thenReturn(objectMapper);
when(objectMapper.constructType(type)).thenReturn(jType);
```

I am getting below error

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'. For example:
>
> ```
>   when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
> ```
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>
> - you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. Those methods cannot be stubbed/verified.
> - inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
> - the parent of the mocked class is not public. It is a limitation of the mock engine.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mock a static method. [This is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463733/mockito-mock-a-static-void-method-with-mockito-mockstatic/64464855#64464855), but if you still want to do that, you need to use Mockito's version 3.4.0 or higher [mockStatic method](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48) (`mockito-inline` dependency should be used).

```java
var objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
when(objectMapper.constructType(type)).thenReturn(jType);
try (var mocked = mockStatic(Json.class)) {
    mocked.when(Json::mapper).thenReturn(objectMapper);
    // execute the tested code
 }
```

[See multiple examples here](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/mockito/mock-static/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/MockitoStaticVoidTest.java).